# how to change the layer color on mouse hover using kineticjs?

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

Generating the map (**svg path via canvas**) using kineticjs.

using kineticjs plugin, map generate successfully..

Need to be highlight the layer background color on mouse hover ?

but i can able to show the alert box on mouse hover...

```
jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/dqhzjnut/4/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nodes are inside `layer`. So you need to redraw `layer':

```
    pathnorthen.on('mouseout', function () {
        //alert("mouse out");
        this.fill('#00dddd');
        layer.draw();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dqhzjnut/6/

Comment: i have a map &  trying to zoom in & zoom out on the mousewheel, my fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/prasadraja07/dqhzjnut/23/ ..pls refer the zoom in & zoom out script http://jsfiddle.net/dariospagnolo/8ag9h2nv/ ..i have tried this script...but i cant able to zoom in & zoom out...can you help to resolve this